# Selecting columns from mulitple table join in SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am joining 3 table in SQLAlchemy Core and selecting all columns as follows:

```
rows = self.db.execute(self.execs.join(
                         self.orders.join(self.instruments)
                      ).select(whereClause)).reduce_columns())
```

It works well but if I want to select a subset of columns:

```
reqdCols = [order.c.id, exec.c.last_modified, instruments.type]
rows = self.db.execute(self.execs.join(
                         self.orders.join(self.instruments)
                      ).select(reqdCols, whereClause)).reduce_columns())
```

It doesn't works and gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/apps/qtdist/pkgs/pub/cpython/python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 807, in select
    return Select(collist, whereclause, from_obj=[self], **kwargs)
  File "/apps/qtdist/pkgs/pub/cpython/python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 2219, in __init__
    whereclause).self_group(against=operators._asbool)
  File "/apps/qtdist/pkgs/pub/cpython/python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 3438, in _literal_as_text
    "SQL expression object or string expected."
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected.
```

Alternative would be to use select instead of Join.select and make it implicit join with where clauses:

```
joinConditions = (orders.c.colx == execs.colx) & (execs.c.coly == instruments.c.coly)
select(reqdCols).where(and_(whereClause, joinConditions)
```

But I would prefer explicit join over implicit for performance reasons. Is there any way to select subset of columns using explicit joins?

Comment: will you please give full traceback?

Comment: Where is `whereClause` initialized ?

Comment: I have simplified it. In actual code whereClause is actually a tuple of clauses and is being called as: select(and_(*whereClauses)). Also stacktrace is from python REPL without the where clause as I am first trying it out from interpreter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
j = join(table1, table2)   #optional third argument is join on part like table1.c.c1 == table2.c.c1

r = db.execute(select([table1.c.x, table2.c.y]).select_from(j)
```